# dependencies error when add firebase libraries

Tags: android, android-studio

When add firebase in

dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

Or

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
```

Or

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1
```

It shows error under implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' that All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes).

When I sync the app no error but when install the app it shows you app has been stopped (Crashing during run time).

When remove the firebase dependencies and run, my app it's working fine.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image]

Comment: Check the libraries in your project manually via file explorer and detect-update the libraries that are using the older version than 28. (Customtabs seems like one of them)

Comment: What is error that you get run-time, please put it here.

Answer (score 0):

When you include dependencies, they too, will sometimes include dependencies of their own. Some of the firebase libraries happen to include support libraries at a lower version than 28. When you hover over the error message for appcompat-v7 it should tell you what library is lower than 28. You may have to click 'show more' on the error message. Once you figure out which one it is, include that exact same library but version 28. Resync your gradle and you're good to go. Also, you might have to do this multiple times because some firebase libraries include multiple lower version support libraries and the error message will only show you one library at a time.